# Why did latter Rabbis study Torah in solitude?

Tags: torah-study, rabbis

From the Talmudic discourse, it appears that there's a special merit of learning Torah in Beis Midrash especially in Chavrutah or with students.

However, I recognize an emerging pattern of the latter renowned Ashkenazi and Sefardic Rabbis that after *teaching* in a Yeshiva, preferred seclusion and studying Torah at home for decades.

Why is it?

Comment: Could you give examples to whom you refer.

Comment: ומנין שאפילו אחד שיושב ועוסק בתורה ששכינה עמו שנאמר בכל המקום אשר אזכיר את שמי אבוא אליך וברכתיך

Comment: Because if they were in Beis Medrash they would have to spend their entire time answering questions and would have no time to learn anything new. Many major Rabbis still have chavrusas though

Comment: It wasnt written down then so they needed each other. I refer you to the tanya shulchan aruch.